# how to execute the apex schedular job in developer console?

Tags: batch

please give me the example program of apex schedular job.How to run the developer console that code give one example. please Give some ideas.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have a Schedulable class created? You can schedule it using the system.schedule command:

```
system.schedule('Name of Job', '0 0 * * * ?', new MySchedulableClass());
```

Where '0 0 * * * ?' is a CRON expression to run the job every hour.

More details here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm

Answer (score 1):

This simple script should be all you need if you want to test your class in the dev console.

```
scheduledClassExample abc = new scheduledClassExample();
abc.execute(null);
```

Comment: The execute method of a class that implements Schedulable interface can not be execute by a user. System.schedule(jobName, cronExpression, schedulableClass) should be used.

Comment: @DenisPereverzev I have used that script in the dev console execution window for months and it works just fine.

Comment: I can confirm this worked for me as well, from an admin account.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
String CRON_EXP = '0 30 * * * ?';
SWD_SoftwareDownloadScheduler sch = new SWD_SoftwareDownloadScheduler();
system.schedule('SWD_SoftwareDownloadScheduler - Hourly (TEST)', CRON_EXP, sch);
```

This runs hourly 30 minutes past the hour.

Link for generating CRON expressions - http://www.cronmaker.com/

Comment: give one example for  Schedule an Apex class every 10 minutes

Comment: can you give example of Schedule an Apex class and howto run it

Comment: Set this String CRON_EXP = '*/10 * * * *';

Comment: Replace this SWD_SoftwareDownloadScheduler with your own class name too

Answer (score 0):

We can use Cron expression to run scheduled job-in-developer-console.
Referal link:- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12058_01/doc/doc.1014/e12030/cron_expressions.htm

```
  Datetime dt = Datetime.now().addMinutes(1);
  String CRON_EXP = '0 '+ dt.minute() + ' * ' + dt.day() + ' ' + dt.month() + ' ? ' + dt.year();
  ScheduleBatch.SchedulerMethod('Sample_Heading', CRON_EXP, new ScheduleBatch () );
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
apexScheduledJob myJob = new apexScheduledJob ();
String sch = '0 0 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22 ? * *';
System.schedule('My Job', sch, myJob);
```

Answer (score -1):

Run a Schedule Job NOW

```
ScheduleSalesTargets c = new ScheduleSalesTargets();
c.execute(null);
```

OR

Check the Time Now, if it is, let's say 10:39 AM, in your clock, then set the minute to 41. This will schedule the job for 10:41 AM just two minutes from now. But, if you set minute value to 38, then it will schedule to next hour 11:38 AM

```
ScheduleSalesTargets c = new ScheduleSalesTargets();
String sch = '0 0 * * * ?';
System.schedule('Sales Target Job11',  '0 41 * * * ?', c);
```